# CSV file appears in commas in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file that I have been trying to upload into R. The problem is that after I put

```
read.csv("...",header=T,sep=",")
```

the data appears not to be properly spaced, i.e. it appears in R exactly as it appears in my CSV file. I have watched many R-tutorials about uploading files and for everyone the file appears properly spaced. How can I fix the issue here?
[image]

Comment: post a small example of what it looks like and what you'd expect.

Comment: @lebatsnok Sure, check my edit. Look how messy it appears. Is there anyway to make it look normal?Thanks.

Comment: take a look at ```?read.table``` ?read.csv``` and ```?read.csv2```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `read.csv2` - apparently you have semicolons (";") instead of commas (",") as separators

Comment: Btw you don't need `header=TRUE` nor `sep=","` with `read.csv` as these are the defaults (unlike in `read.table`). And csv files are often produced by excel - if you get "semicolon separated values" instead of real csv when saving as csv in excel then you probably have set ";" as "list separator" somewhere in your windows setting(probably control panel --> international settings). This is common in countries where comma is used as decimal separator

Comment: This is due to the default settings of Excel you are using Excel with a European locale (have to use `read.csv2`) than with the American locale (have to use `read.csv`).